# Implementing BottomSheetDialog in Compose ui

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

How can I implement `BottomSheetDialog` in jetpack compose ui.
I tried using `BottomDrawerLayout` and `DropdownPopup`. But niether of them worked for me.

Comment: Check this link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-material/integration-tests/samples/src/main/java/androidx/ui/material/samples/DrawerSamples.kt

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

[bottomsheetdialog-compose](https://github.com/holixfactory/bottomsheetdialog-compose) is a library that allows you to use BottomsheetDialog like Dialog's interface.

```
// module's build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "com.holix.android:bottomsheetdialog-compose:1.0.3"
}

// Composable function
BottomSheetDialog(
  onDismissRequest = { ... },
  properties = BottomSheetDialogProperties(...)
) {
  // content
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and instead of inflating a layout file in the dialog's `onCreateView` use `compose` to implement your layout.

You can read [here](https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment-android-6ac7dc36e6ac) on how to implement a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Comment: Do you mean to implement layout.xml and use that layout file in compose ?

Comment: No, compose replaces the need for a layout.xml read the Jetpack compose tutorial to understand how to write layouts using compose https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

Comment: So `BottomSheetDialogFragment ` is part of google material. So, I need to include google material file separately in gradle. Because I cannot see any such thing in `androidx.ui.material`

Comment: Yeah, you need to add it as a dependency

Comment: `setContent` is part of `Activity` and 'ViewGroup'. So,cannot use `setContent` inside Fragment.

Comment: You can do something like this: https://gist.github.com/gilgoldzweig/f6d69ae252a35c193996abe67203b488

Answer (score 0):

You can use ComposeView in your xml of your bottomsheet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
            android:id="@+id/composeView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Then in your Bottohsheet kotlin class, you can set compose content like this:

```
private fun initView(){
        binding.composeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                XyzScreen(requireContext())
            }
        }
    }
```